# Parsing data, scanf?

Tags: c++, parsing, scanf

I am quite new to progamming, I would like to parse data in a format like this:

4 ((182, 207), (385, 153), (638, 639), (692, 591))

First number states the number of pairs that will occur. I want to save first number of each pair as X axis and second number of each pair as Y axis.
In my head for now I wanted to save entire line via scanf and then try to work around the amount of brackets and commas but I am not sure if that is the right method or how to implement it properly. I do not want to use any built in containers or string. I tried to do it straight away via scanf doing something like

```
for(int i= 0; i < pair_count;i++){
scanf("(%d, %d)",tabx[i],taby[i])

}
```

but it does not work :(. I don't know how to format the scanf correctly I guess or my idea on how to do it is completely wrong.

Comment: why use scanf? use std::cin instead or std::stringstream instead?

Comment: if your `tabx`, `taby` are arrays of `int`s, first thing to fix would be changing  `scanf` arguments to `tabx + i`, `taby + i` (pointers to values are required for `scanf`). Second thing - you should somehow arrange skipping of ',' between `(...)` at least.

Comment: I think scanf is always a bad idea because it makes your program very brittle to data anomalies.  Instead, read in a line at a time (e.g. into a string), and then do your parsing on each line.

Comment: I think that scanf is faster than cin? Or isn't it?

Comment: Prefer to read into a string and use `sscanf`.  Also check the return value of `scanf`.  Search the internet for "scanf security" for a list of issues with `scanf`.  The function `fscanf` is safer and can be used with `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to input all matching characters. It's a bit tricky, because `,` is not present after last pair of numbers.

Following sample code solves your problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    // 4 ((182, 207), (385, 153), (638, 639), (692, 591))

    int pair_count;
    scanf("%d", &pair_count);
    scanf(" (");

    int* tabx = new int[pair_count];
    int* taby = new int[pair_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count-1; ++i) {
        if (scanf("(%d, %d), ", &tabx[i], &taby[i]) < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Input error!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if (scanf("(%d, %d))", &tabx[pair_count-1], &taby[pair_count-1]) < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d\n", tabx[i], taby[i]);
    }

    delete[] tabx;
    delete[] taby;
}
```

Alternatively, you can read the entire input to string and replace all `(`, `)` and `,` with  (space). After that you can simply parse numbers. On the other hand, this removes validation of data format.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` expects the address to a variable, not the variable itself.  So try:

```
   scanf("(%d, %d)",&tabx[i],&taby[i]);
```

You can also try to use c++ streams:

```
  for(int i= 0; i < pair_count;i++){
      char d1,d2,d3;
      if ( (cin >> d1 >> tabx[i] >> d2 >> taby[i] >> d3) && d1=='(' && d3==')' && d2==',') {
         ... //process data
       }
       else cout << "Wrong input !"<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: Good to see a streams approach, but need to handle the comma between pairs too....